# How to create a sub- domain in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am trying to create a sub-domain in laravel. The subdomain will be something like `merchant.example.com` and they will be more links such as `merchant.example.com/login` `merchant.example.com/myaccount`  so this is what I tired

```
Route::get('.partner/', array(
'as' => 'partner-home',
'uses' => 'HomeController@partnerHome'
));
```

but just redirect me to the main domain. Any idea how to this please.

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#sub-domain-routing

Comment: What do you mean? Update what?

Comment: @lukasgeiter Sorry I might I don't understand it. The example is half complete they is no explanation plus it aint a wildcard sub.domain. It always gonna be partner.main-domain-name.com so the word `partner` will be they

Comment: That actually makes it even simpler... Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register a route group to have a certain domain:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'partner.myapp.com'), function(){
    Route::get('/', array(
        'as' => 'partner-home',
        'uses' => 'HomeController@partnerHome'
    ));
});
```

Comment: thanks but do i need to hard code "myapp.com"? can't i get the actually domain be better?

Comment: Note that there is no save way to figure out the current domain (because there are tlds with two segments like `.co.uk`. You could add a value `domain` inside `config/app.php`. And retrieve it like `Config::get('app.domain')` to make it configurable for different environments.